# PhantomJS trying to take a screenshot

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, phantomjs, screenshot

I'm using a library called [heimdall](https://github.com/DistilledLtd/heimdall) in order to take screenshots of a web page. Everything it's works perfectly fine in some cases and not at all in some others. I've to take some screenshots of each like from a sitemap but some of the links are just not working this library for some reason and I'm not able to take a screenshot.

I've made some debug and I fond that in order to take a screenshot is going to be executed this command.

```
phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any mypath/heimdall/take_screenshot.js LINK --width 1280 --height 800 --useragent "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36" --dir Data --ext png --name NAME_FROM_LINK
```

Here is the tricky part, if I'm using the terminal(I'm running Ubuntu 18.04) this command:

```
LINK=https://lajumate.ro/tag_Casa+de+vanzare_imobiliare_in-prahova.html
NAME_FROM_LINK=tag_Casa+de+vanzare_imobiliare_in-prahova

phantomjs --ssl-protocol=any mypath/heimdall/take_screenshot.js LINK --width 1280 --height 800 --useragent "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36" --dir Data --ext png --name NAME_FROM_LINK
```

I'm not going to get any screenshot and also I'm going to receive this output

OUTPUT:

> setting width to 1280
>
> setting height to 800
>
> setting useragent to Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
>
> setting dir to Data
>
> setting ext to png
>
> Status: fail
>
> Reason: Operation canceled
>
> Reason URL: https://lajumate.ro/tag_Casa+de+vanzare_imobiliare_in-
>   prahova.html
>
> TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.
>
> TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.

BUT, if I will run the same command but with for example this LINK and NAME_FROM_LINK which are:

```
LINK=https://lajumate.ro/garsoniera-pe-bd-mihai-viteazu-8528569.html
NAME_FROM_LINK=garsoniera-pe-bd-mihai-viteazu-8528569
```

Everything it works perfectly fine and I'm going to receive my screenshot and also this output

OUTPUT:

> setting width to 1280
>
> setting height to 800
>
> setting useragent to Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>
> Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
>
> setting dir to Data
>
> setting ext to png
>
> ARG[height] 800
>
> ARG[width] 1280
>
> ARG[dir] Data
>
> ARG[name] phantomimg
>
> ARG[ext] png
>
> ARG[quality] 100
>
> ARG[useragent] Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
>
> ARG[croptovisible] false
>
> ARG[maxexecutiontime] 30000
>
> ARG[renderafter] 7000
>
> ARG[resourcetimeout] 3000
>
> SAVED IMAGE: Data/phantomimg.png
>
> TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.
>
> TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.

Could any of you explain to me what's happending here and how can I fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue with a script that does not use heimdal but calls `webpage.render` directly. IMHO this looks like a bug in PhantomJS unfortunately.